# Font Size Resizes by Stepper

Tags: ios, xcode, uistepper

I want my app to be when you click the stepper it will resize the font in a `UITextView`. The problem is I'm getting errors.

```
- (IBAction)myStepper:(id)sender {
    [myStepper setMinimumValue:14.0]
    self.myStepper.maximumValue =20.0;
    UIFont newSize = [myTextView fontWithSize:self.stepper.value];
    self.myTextView.font = newSize;
}
```

This all of my code, am I missing something?

Comment: what kind of errors did you get exactly?

Comment: Property of 'myStepper' not found on object of type in ViewController & Property of 'stepper' not found on object of type in ViewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would clean your method a bit like this:

```
- (IBAction)myStepperValueChanged:(UIStepper *)sender {
    [sender setMinimumValue:14.0];
    [sender setMaximumValue:20.0];
    UIFont * newSize = [UIFont fontWithName:myTextView.font.fontName size:sender.value];
    [self.myTextView setFont:newSize];
}
```

---

but I'd put the first two lines into the `-viewDidLoad` method as part of the standard init procedure, if they are static values in runtime using the outlet's name (I assume it is `myStepper` in your class):

```
[myStepper setMinimumValue:14.0];
[myStepper setMaximumValue:20.0];
```

or I'd set these values in the *Interface Builder*, and you'd not need to deal with any outlet for your stepper at all.

---

*NOTE: it is hard to tell which solution would fit better for you, you have not shared too much information which could help me to recommend a specific solution.*

Comment: Thanks... but the all the 'sender' have error sign by them

Comment: could you be more specific about which error you did receive here?

Comment: It doesn't show the errors, but when I build the simulator it crashes.

Comment: what does the crash report say?

Comment: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: what is the reason of the exception? (that appears on the console...)

Comment: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key changeFontSize.

Comment: [<ViewController 0xbbdd400> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]

Comment: you probably does not set the file's owner and or connected its properties well. your problem is not in this code fragment what you have posted.

Comment: Thanks Everyone! I appreciate you all taking the time, but nothing is working:(

Comment: I was taking another stab at this and i figured it all except for one error. It says there is no class method for selector "fontWithSize". Please help

Comment: I'm not sure about why you have not copied and pasted this snippet to your project yet... and why are you forcing to use your own code which is not correct? the `UIFont` have no such selector like `+fontWithSize:`. it never ever has, it has only `–fontWithSize:`. I'm sure your are lack of essentials here, because you clearly can't make difference between an _instance_ and a _class_ method – additionally the `UITextField` has not even any of such methods.

Comment: Have you even tried your code yet? I tried yours but when i ran the simulator it crashed.

Comment: yes, I have tried both on simulator and on real device. as we discussed before the crash is not in my code, that is coming from your app somewhere else, but as long as you are not able to provide proper information about the crash – that is just a dead-end on my side, regarding my code is correct syntactically and logically as well.

Comment: What are all the properties that I need. I think that is my problem.

Comment: Thanks Man!! It Worked!! :)  I appreciate you taking the time with me!

Comment: Do you think you could help me with another question? Click here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25298858/3899954

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `self` and a semicolon in the first line:

```
[self.myStepper setMinimumValue:14.0];
```

And an asterisk and `self` in this line, and `stepper` should be `myStepper`:

```
UIFont *newSize = [self.myTextView fontWithSize:self.myStepper.value];
```

Comment: You beat me to it by a second ;)

Comment: That fixed some of it. but there is still an error by : myStepper, setMinimumValue, maximumValue, & myTextView.

Comment: Updated my answer with another problem I found.

Comment: I still have error signs by: myStepper, setMinimumValue, maximumValue, & myTextView.

Comment: Added another issue. By the way, if you click on the errors, or go to the issue navigator (Command-4), you should be able to see more info on what’s wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For easier code-reading, you shouldn't give your action method the same name of your UISteppert property. Change it to `-(IBAction)stepperValueChanged:(id)sender`  for example.

You don't need to set the min and max value in this method, but in your initialization methods

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
     // Various implementation

    self.myStepper.minimumValue = 14;
    self.myStepper.maximumValue = 20.0;
}

- (IBAction) stepperValueChanged:(id)sender 
{
     self.myTextView.font = [UIFont fontWithSize:self.myStepper.value];
}
```

It looks like you are some issues understanting the differences between method and properties, you should read some documentation and tutorials if you're beginning development (and welcome to the development world ;) ).

**EDIT :**

The property myStepper doesn't exists in your class. If you use interface builder, you have to link your stepper to an UIStepper property : this apple tutorial will help you : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/articles-connections_bindings/CreatingOutlet.html .
Otherwise, if you don't use Interface Builder, you must add an UIStepper property to your class and allocate it by yourself.

Comment: I two errors errors - 1. ` self.myStepper.minimumValue = 14;` & 2. ` self.myTextView.font [myTextViewfontWithSize:self.myStepper.value];`

Comment: Be more specifics about the errors you have : click on the red "error" icon left to the text editor and a more-detailed error will be shown.

Comment: They both say Property 'mystepper'not found on object of type of ViewController

Comment: Thanks! the UIStepper property worked! I only have one error now in the IBAction - No visible @interface for 'UITextView' declares the selector 'fontWithSize'

Comment: Youps, my bad here, use [UIView fontWithSize:  instead of [myTextView fontWithSize: - The answer was updated.

Comment: it says No Known class method for selector fontwithsize... Also I'm making the UIStepper to change the font in a UITextView. Do I need a property for UITextView?

Comment: @DoughnutMan, have you check my answer yet?

Comment: Typo in the comment but not in the answer, use UIFont... End of the day, i start being tired ^^ Yes, you need a property for the textview too, or any "object" you want to keep a reference to within your class.