# Scroll View without Auto Layout

Tags: uiscrollview

In my app I have buttons in a `UIScrollView` that when they are clicked it displays text in a `UITextView`. In my app I can't use auto layout; but my `UIScrollView` won't work.

How can I use `UIScrollView` when I don't have "use auto layout" on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

.h

```
IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollerName;
```

.m [viewDidLoad]

```
    [Scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [Scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(x, y)];

self->Scroller.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin);
```

or just:

```
    [Scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [Scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(x, y)];
```